# Determining the relative size of $a^n$ and $b^m$ without using logarithms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Example, which is larger $ 17^{105} $ vs $ 31^{84} $? Make the deternimination without resorting to logs, or Excel either.

Comment: The only way to do that, that I know of, is to find a third number that they both can be compared to, where one is bigger and the other is smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ (16 + 1)^{105} \ = \  (2^4 + 1)^{105} \ = \ 2^{420} \ + \ 105 \cdot \ 2^{416} \ + \ \ldots  $$

*versus*

$$ (32 - 1)^{84} \ = \ (2^5 - 1)^{84} \ = \ 2^{420} \ - \ 84 \cdot \ 2^{415} \ + \ \ldots $$

Note that all of the "binomial terms" for $ \ 17^{105} \ $ are positive, while those for $ \ 31^{84} \ $ alternate signs. (**EDIT:** Also, since the exponent for $ \ 32^{84} \ $ is lower, the binomial coefficients in its expansion are smaller, so there is no possibility that the positive terms will somehow "catch up" with, much less surpass, those for $ \ 17^{105} \ $ .)

Comment: I chose this answer as best based on the fact that I have several other similar comparisons to make and this method seems most generally adaptable.

Comment: The particular numbers used and the fact that the first term in both binomial expansions are identical made me suspicious that this problem was _designed_ with such an approach in mind.  The inequality methods presented on this page are good ones to keep in mind more generally.

Comment: I'll put 'em in the toolbox.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

$$(84,105)=21$$

So, it is sufficient to check $17^5<=>31^4$

$31^2=961,17^2=289$

Now $\dfrac{961}{289}<4\implies31^4<17^4\cdot4^2<17^4\cdot17=17^5$

Comment: The three answers that I got for this question are completely different approaches to the problem, all fascinating and helpful.  Unfortunately, I could only mark one of them as best.  However, this in no way reduces the value of your effort to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$ 2\cdot17 > 31$$ 
$$\implies (2\cdot17)^{84} > 31^{84} $$
$$\implies 2^{84}\cdot17^{84} > 31^{84} $$

Since $$105-84=21$$
And $$2^4<17$$
$$\implies (2^4)^{21}<17^{21}$$
$$\implies 2^{84}<17^{21}$$

Clearly $$17^{21}\cdot17^{84} > 31^{84}$$
$$\implies 17^{105} > 31^{84}$$

Comment: The three answers that I got for this question are completely different approaches to the problem, all fascinating and helpful.  Unfortunately, I could only mark one of them as best.  However, this in no way reduces the value of your effort to me.  Thanks.